# access javascript window.myvariable in asp code behind of child form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have a parent form that calls a child form using this javascript code to pass a json object.

```
        var w = window.open("childForm.aspx");
        w.myJsonObj = myJSONObject;
```

How can I access this variable in the childForm.aspx onload event so I can deserialize?

Comment: You'll either have to post it to the page in question, or you could perhaps append it as a querystring parameter in your window.open() call, stringified and URL encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables are purely client-side, so they aren't accessible server-side (from code-behind). To get access to it server-side, you have to store that value somewhere where the server can access it.

There are many options, but here's one: create a hidden field to store the value in, give that field an id and the `runat="server"` attribute (so it's accessible from code-behind), and update your javascript to populate it.

Hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="SomeUniqueID" runat="server"/>
```

Javascript (without JQuery):

```
document.getElementById('<%= SomeUniqueID.ClientID %>').setAttribute("value", myJSONObject);
```

Javascript (with JQuery):

```
$('#<%= SomeUniqueID.ClientID %>').val(myJSONObject);
```

Comment: Okay, If I want to pass this value to a new page, which opens and processes the data how would be best way to do that? I do not want to use url parameter because this is a large serialized custom object. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to pass it in the query string then you could store the value in the session. So, in your code behind on the page that gets the value, save it to session like this: `Session["someVariableName"] = SomeUniqueID.Value;`. Then on the page that needs to use that value, read it back out of session: `var jsonString = Session["someVariableName"] as string;`.